# what is the probability of sampling a uniform distributed uncountable set and recieving a certain countable subset

Tags: statistics, cardinals

I would assume that the chance would be $0%$ as $0=\lim\frac{1}{n}$ but since the equivalent would be something along the lines of $\frac{\aleph_0}{\aleph_1}$ I am not sure.

If $0=\frac{\aleph_0}{\aleph_1}$ would that not mean that anything would be an infinite subset when randomly sampled from an uncountable set, even elements that are not in the set with uncountable cardinality to begin with?

There is probably some statistics and cardinality knowledge that i am missing but hopefully someone can give me some understanding :O

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE! I think $\frac{\aleph_0}{\aleph_1}$ is not the right idea here. The answer doesn't have much to do with cardinal arithmetic. What do you mean exactly by "receiving a certain countable subset"? For example, would this answer your question: "suppose $X$ is a continuous real-valued random variable, and $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ is countable. Then $\Bbb P(X \in A) = 0$"? This fact just follows from "countable additivity of $\Bbb P$".